# Alert values properties of an object related to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am no able to alert object values corresponding to the id of area tag.

My code is,

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".wholecirclewrapper area").click(function(){      
                if($(this).hasClass("active")) {        
                    return false;
                }       
                var choice = $(this).attr("id");    
                $.each(results.States, function(i, item) {
                    var st=results.States[i].Name;
                    if(choice==st)
                    {
                        alert(results.States[i].ISHI);  
                    }
                });

            });

        });
```

My Html code is

```
            <div id="mapdiv">
        <img src="india.gif"  alt="India" usemap="#indiamap" />
        <map name="indiamap" class="wholecirclewrapper">
            <area class="specificshelfdiv1" id="AndraPradesh" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="#"  />
            <area class="specificshelfdiv2" id="ArunachalPradesh" shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="#"  />
            <area class="specificshelfdiv3" id="Assam" shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="#"   />     
        </map> 
    </div>
```

My external json looks like

```
      var results={"States":[
        { "Name" : "AndraPradesh" , "ISHI" : "19.5 (Serious)" ,"Literacy rate" : "67.7" ,"Population rate" : "84,665,533" ,"NFHS" : "29.8" ,"Tap water" : "69.9"}, 
        { "Name" : "ArunachalPradesh" , "ISHI" : "Not estimated" ,"Literacy rate" : "67" ,"Population rate" : "1,382,611" ,"NFHS" : "29.6" ,"Tap water" : "65.5"}, 
        { "Name" : "Assam" , "ISHI" : "19.8 (Serious)" ,"Literacy rate" : "73.2" ,"Population rate" : "31,169,272" ,"NFHS" : "35.8" ,"Tap water" : "10.5"} 
     ]
     };
```

i am calling json via

```
           <script src="json_states.json" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not JSON, this is a JavaScript object.

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Inspect what `choice` and `results.States[i].Name` are.

Comment: I ran the script and it worked for me, I think **results** isn't properly defined in your example

Comment: this is external json file. json_states.json... I am calling it by <script src="json_states.json" type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: worked for you? thatz weird. It worked may be coz u considered it as javascript obj. But it is not

Comment: If the code in that file starts with `var results=`, then it is not JSON, it's simply JavaScript. An object literal **is not** JSON.

Comment: ok, tried another example with an external file and it still works, as expected, see my answer below for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try replacing **alert** with **console.log**

```
console.log(results.States[i].ISHI);
```

Then in Chrome press F12, go to Console and see if the values are printed.
As a rule of thumb always use console.log instead of alert as it's more powerful and easier to use.

Update:

Try loading the scripts in the following order in the document head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="json_states.json"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
...
</script>
```

Also see this example that I wrote: http://radulescu.me/overflow/1/

Comment: well, it could be that the OP has disabled alerts in her browser

Comment: @ValentinRădulescu am using the same order

Comment: @ErmaIsabel I've uploaded an example to my server, it works perfectly in Chrome. Try running it http://radulescu.me/overflow/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working in [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Br8VQ/1/) here. I'm adding another element `<p id="result"></p>` and instead of alerting I'm setting the `.text()` of this element and it's fine. Try this method instead of `alert` and see what you get.

```
$(".wholecirclewrapper area").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        return false;
    }

    var choice = $(this).attr("id");

    $.each(results.States, function(i, item) {
        var st = results.States[i].Name;
        if (choice == st) {
            $("#result").text(results.States[i].ISHI);
        }
    });
});
```

Are you using a popup blocker of some kind, as these prevent certain scripts executing. If not then I suggest you check for script errors in your browser debug environment.

---

**EDIT** - If you're loading your json from an external file, instead of including it in the header have you tried loading it like this:

```
$.getJSON('json_states.json', function(data) {
    var results = data;

    // do the rest of your script here
});
```

Comment: Thank you...but it is not a javascript object. I am calling an external  json file by <script src="json_states.json" type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: I tried that but na... gets the following error - XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/***/json_states.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @ErmaIsabel: that's a cross-domain issue (which is expected if your website is trying to invoke json from your D: drive), can you move the json file into the same location as your executing code.

Comment: it is in the same folder location. I dnt knw why code is giving such an error

Comment: @terric.. Thank you...i got the output

Answer (score 1):

Its been said 3 times already, but since you seem to be ignoring it, or not understanding, i'll post it again.

```
var results={"States":[
    { "Name" : "AndraPradesh" , "ISHI" : "19.5 (Serious)" ,"Literacy rate" : "67.7" ,"Population rate" : "84,665,533" ,"NFHS" : "29.8" ,"Tap water" : "69.9"}, 
    { "Name" : "ArunachalPradesh" , "ISHI" : "Not estimated" ,"Literacy rate" : "67" ,"Population rate" : "1,382,611" ,"NFHS" : "29.6" ,"Tap water" : "65.5"}, 
    { "Name" : "Assam" , "ISHI" : "19.8 (Serious)" ,"Literacy rate" : "73.2" ,"Population rate" : "31,169,272" ,"NFHS" : "35.8" ,"Tap water" : "10.5"} 
 ]
 };
```

IS NOT JSON. It is a Javascript Object.

JSON would just be this:

```
{"States":[
    { "Name" : "AndraPradesh" , "ISHI" : "19.5 (Serious)" ,"Literacy rate" : "67.7" ,"Population rate" : "84,665,533" ,"NFHS" : "29.8" ,"Tap water" : "69.9"}, 
    { "Name" : "ArunachalPradesh" , "ISHI" : "Not estimated" ,"Literacy rate" : "67" ,"Population rate" : "1,382,611" ,"NFHS" : "29.6" ,"Tap water" : "65.5"}, 
    { "Name" : "Assam" , "ISHI" : "19.8 (Serious)" ,"Literacy rate" : "73.2" ,"Population rate" : "31,169,272" ,"NFHS" : "35.8" ,"Tap water" : "10.5"} 
 ]}
```

Im not sure if the .json file extension will cause issues with any browsers, but if your defining a variable inside the file, it should just be .js... because thats exactly what it is.